# How to share mercurial hooks with your team for jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I am aware that I need to add hooks in my .hg/hgrc file. I could add something like:

```
commit.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null <jenkins root>/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<repository remote url>
incoming.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null <jenkins root>/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<repository remote url>
```

but I think this only applies to my local machine and not for the whole team.